# TS2315: Type ShopifyCollectionProduct is not generic. -- Even though type is definitely generic

Tags: typescript, generics

Below I have 3 types (I have removed all the irrelevant members from the example).

```
export interface ShopifyPick<IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'> {
  quantity: IsInformed extends 'informed' ? number : never
}

export type ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'> =
  ShopifyOneTimeBoxProduct | ShopifyGiftCardProduct | ShopifyPick<IsInformed>

export interface ShopifyCollection<
  ShopifyCollectionProduct,
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'
> {
  products: Array<ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed>> | null
}
```

The last line (declaring the `products` property in `ShopifyCollection` gives the error":

> TS2315: Type  ShopifyCollectionProduct  is not generic.

But as you can see, `ShopifyCollectionProduct` has a generic type argument, so it is generic.

What is the problem here?

---

### Update

A commenter noticed that I am shadowing `ShopifyCollectionProduct`. However, they assumed that the *use* of the generic argument intended to refer to the original type, not the generic that shadowed it, which is incorrect.

It's strange, but the previous code (the code before I added the whole concept of `Provided`) still worked.  `ShopifyCollectionProduct` was indeed the name of the generic argument, but it appears that it was somehow being inferred as being constrained to the type of the same name. `const picks: ShopifyCollection<ShopifyPick>` indeed was a `ShopifyCollection` whose `products` were of type `ShopifyPick`. Below is a "corrected" version of the original code.

```
export type ShopifyCollectionProduct =
  | ShopifyOneTimeBoxProduct
  | ShopifyGiftCardProduct
  | ShopifyPick

export interface ShopifyCollection<ProductType extends ShopifyCollectionProduct> {
  products: Array<ProductType> | null
}
```

So now we are back where we started and where we ended up, because this code, which I hope more clearly illustrates my actual intention, fails in the exact same way as I originally posted it.

```
export type ShopifyCollectionProduct<
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'uninformed'
> = ShopifyOneTimeBoxProduct | ShopifyGiftCardProduct | ShopifyPick<IsInformed>

export interface ShopifyCollection<
  ProductType extends ShopifyCollectionProduct,
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'
> {
  // TS2315: Type  ProductType  is not generic.
  products: Array<ProductType<IsInformed>> | null
}
```

I also tried reversing the type arguments:

```
export interface ShopifyCollection<
  IsInformed extends Informed,
  ProductType extends ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed>
>
```

But the error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing the the type you want to use.

```
// This is a generic type that has a generic type parameter named IsInformed 
export type ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'> =
  ShopifyOneTimeBoxProduct | ShopifyGiftCardProduct | ShopifyPick<IsInformed>

// This is a generic type that has 2 generic type parameters:
//   `ShopifyCollectionProduct` which is unconstrained
//   `IsInformed` which is constrained and defaulted
export interface ShopifyCollection<
  ShopifyCollectionProduct, // <-- here
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'
> {
  products: Array<ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed>> | null
}
```

The highlighted line has a generic type parameter that has the same name as the a type declared above, but is *wholly* unrelated.

So what's happening here is that inside the `ShopifyCollection` type, `ShopifyCollectionProduct` is an unconstrained generic parameter that is roughly equivalent to `unknown`. This shadows the type you declare above it. And `unknown<IsInformed>` doesn't make any sense.

If you change that name to *anything* else the error goes away because now `ShopifyCollectionProduct` is no longer shadowed inside this type.

```
export interface ShopifyCollection<
  T, // <-- here
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'
> {
  products: Array<ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed>> | null
} // fine
```

It's hard to know exactly what your intent is here, but that's how you fix this.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwPYCcC2EAmUC8UDkAloqhpvlAD4FxLAC0xy6W+AUGxAB5irBTFgEFAgCGAY2gBlABZIwhBCAAKhcQGsAPDADO8ZmSjchcTDtgkW2PEUtl8APigBvNlCgBHAK6i4wQqAAXLB6dlhGXCZmBEykrFAA-FBwXmgARsJQwXAQAG7CbAC+HNy8KPygkFCy8oogAMJIADZNEOL+SHDKKEiYXu3aoQbhxhCm5vpx1jFh5E44bAD0i+5U1XIKSgDyOQAqhBgAQkhc3b39wEsr7tQ1myAA4orA9aIomGd97W5rd3WqGkGkysDhKPD4Aj8wjEknWtSUjRabQ6cE0P12ABofrpgYZRuMLMNprYiewnK53GAel9gDpggBBFAoUQgTR-BHNVrtQidT4XIGzBxOagpFpFIA)

---

But that generic parameter seems entirely unused anyway, so perhaps you just want this?

```
export interface ShopifyCollection<
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed',
> {
  products: Array<ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed>> | null
}
```

---

Update

So why do you get a similar error in this code?

```
export interface ShopifyCollection<
  ProductType extends ShopifyCollectionProduct,
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'
> {
  // TS2315: Type  ProductType  is not generic.
  products: Array<ProductType<IsInformed>> | null
}
```

To answer that let's vastly simplify this:

```
type HasGeneric<T extends 'a' | 'b'> = { value: T }

type MyType<U extends HasGeneric> = { myType: U }
// Generic type 'HasGeneric' requires 1 type argument(s).(2314)
```

This is a type error because all generic parameters of a type *must* be specified. You can do this explicitly, or with a default type. So we can fix this with a default type.

```
type HasGeneric<T extends 'a' | 'b' = 'a'> = { value: T }
type MyType<U extends HasGeneric> = { myType: U }
```

This has no type errors now, but it's actually equivalent to:

```
type MyType<U extends HasGeneric<'a'>> = { myType: U }
```

And if you try to use it, you'll see that you cannot override the `'a'`

```
type MyTypeWithA = MyType<{ value: 'a' }>
// fine

type MyTypeWithB = MyType<{ value: 'b' }>
/*
Type '{ value: "b"; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'HasGeneric<"a">'.
  Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.(2344)
*/
```

---

So `ProductType` in `ProductType extends ShopifyCollectionProduct` is not itself generic. It extends `ShopifyCollectionProduct<'informed'>`, which is not a generic type because it's generics have already been resolved.

I think maybe you want this?

```
export interface ShopifyCollection<
  ProductType extends ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed>,
  IsInformed extends Informed = 'informed'
> {
  products: Array<ProductType> | null
}
```

Here `ProductType` now extends `ShopifyCollectionProduct<IsInformed>` which has the generic resolved. This is how you proxy generic through to other generics. You accept them and them pass them, just as you would arguments to a function.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwPYCcC2EAmUC8UDkAloqhpvlAD4ECucxy6W+AUCwPTtRoCGm0wABYQAztBpgWoSFADKgpGEIIQABUIBjANYAeACpQIAD2AQ4mEbBJNMAPlxQA3lCXaAXFGAoaEADRQGUiwPAwBfKXBoeUVlEAB5OAg9QgwAISQjVRQkTBoNYAdnaKUVBKSUiHTM7Nz8jy8fKHDpKIUSkABxZWAAYR4UTCycvIK8IrbYroRe-sGakfrvaHDOKABaDbYWYzBUApa5CZUepAAbU4h8wiQ4IdrgHRYoWBF4RjJDEzMLK3esB3wdECNlY9hwTyohxipUSyTSGTuIwh1GKk26fQGiPyyKh7XU2h0MFe1jItjYOz2ATgphQCB4Gla0JAJ3Ol2A1zgj2eWOAekin1M5ksqOOZwuVxuPMJxL+dl8EKJbyC2GMgp+SpsAOBZFBTghYHm+REHgAgigUDwQDoeXzIPZqHAaOcWOEIjI9KJgCaHCLmWK2RydL6pjNMYbgGSDh6RMBUj6jn7WRLOcH0bMef4iCTmJH+dHevGmSzxeybkGEyGMXNhvlM0Ds+QyW7oPmACKF9rFgNl31d5NSrOy-C2XPuz0AUQ7sT7pZTCZnHIH2pzmeXjbYUc9ADEp6Kk7Py0X-f3wzpB8rh3X6A3hxwuAA9Qzm1CWHiWHZsrBAA)

Comment: Thanks, but your very fair assumption happens to be off the mark. Please see my update in the original post and maybe you can help!

Comment: Well seems like you got a few problems, then :) See my update

Comment: That is complex, but clear. "proxy generic through to other generics" is exactly what I figured I was having trouble with. Thank you!!!